# Parity does not compile contract without error

Tags: solidity, parity, contract-debugging, mapping

When I input the following contract into Parity's develop field it does not complain but I also doesn't compile the contract which makes it impossible to deploy. Any suggestions? I tried linting the contract but it seems syntactically correct.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

/// @title Name Resolver for multiple contracts
/// Resolves contract names to their current version's address
contract Register {
    address owner;
    mapping (string => address) public backends;

    function Register() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function changeBackend(string contractName, address newBackend) public onlyOwner() returns (bool) {
        if(newBackend != backends[contractName]) {
            backends[contractName] = newBackend;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it is an error that neither Parity nor atomlinter shows. Using Remix gives the error:

```
"Accessors for mapping with dynamically-sized keys not yet implemented.”
```

So the error can be fixed by changing the mapping to:

```
mapping (bytes32 => address) public backends;
```

And provide a custom getter for the backends:

```
function getBackend(string contractName) returns (address) {
    return backends[keccak256(contractName)];
}
```

Similar procedure with the setter.